# I installed Visual Studio 2017. I am facing an issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After Installing Visual Studio 2017. When I starts the Windows 10 It will automatically open a files which shows the following log. What is it don't know please help

Here is the log file.

```
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v10.0 (Build 14393: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\WAQASI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{AF78E89A-9FF2-4C41-851C-A3B3EDBBC999}\.cr\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Initializing string variable 'DOTNETHOME' to value '[ProgramFiles6432Folder]dotnet'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Initializing string variable 'BUNDLEMONIKER' to value '.NET Core SDK 1.0.0 (x64) Installer'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise /log C:\Users\Waqas Idrees\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170308115057_315_Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.log /quiet /norestart'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value '.NET Core SDK 1.0.0 (x64) Installer (x64)'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[2130:0CC4][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[2130:0CC4][2017-03-08T15:02:39]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '1.0.0.0'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i100: Detect begin, 8 packages
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VCRedist_KeyExists' to value 1
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'VCRedist_KeyValue' to value 'v14.10.25008.00'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i052: Condition '(VCRedist_KeyExists AND VCRedist_KeyValue >= "v14.0.23506.00")' evaluates to true.
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i103: Detected related package: {878A575E-7D6A-4105-BB28-D36AC32941DA}, scope: PerMachine, version: 4.0.20897.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i103: Detected related package: {9D1645C0-1783-4BB4-B099-B23FEC0A220E}, scope: PerMachine, version: 4.0.20897.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i103: Detected related package: {878A575E-7D6A-4105-BB28-D36AC32941DA}, scope: PerMachine, version: 4.0.20897.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i103: Detected related package: {9D1645C0-1783-4BB4-B099-B23FEC0A220E}, scope: PerMachine, version: 4.0.20897.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: VC_redist.x64.exe, state: Present, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i101: Detected package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i200: Plan begin, 8 packages, action: Install
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VC_redist.x64.exe
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_000_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi_rollback.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_000_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_001_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi_rollback.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_001_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_002_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi_rollback.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_002_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_003_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi_rollback.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_003_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_004_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi_rollback.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_004_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_005_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi_rollback.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_005_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_006_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi_rollback.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi' to value 'C:\Users\Waqas_006_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi.log'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: VC_redist.x64.exe, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i201: Planned package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i300: Apply begin
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:02:40]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:02:50]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\WAQASI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{38014EE6-773B-4070-8905-096A41219369}\.be\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322}\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe'
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:02:50]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322}, version: 1.0.0.0
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:02:50]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2130:2D5C][2017-03-08T15:02:50]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe
[2130:2D5C][2017-03-08T15:02:51]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\'
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:52]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3A36F010-62C4-4173-9F25-257F1B0899DD}v4.0.4911\dotnet-sdk-win-x64.1.0.0.msi.
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:52]i305: Verified acquired payload: cabD14AB056D4AE71F6C81FF92C2FC58276 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cabD14AB056D4AE71F6C81FF92C2FC58276, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3A36F010-62C4-4173-9F25-257F1B0899DD}v4.0.4911\dnet-1.cab.
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:52]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3C83FDBB-34EF-401F-AC13-F234BD57FA1A}v1.0.4\dotnet-sharedframework-win-x64.1.0.4.msi.
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:52]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E1197A14-9403-4F4C-8272-38FB20DF8CF5}v4.0.21147\dotnet-hostfxr-win-x64.1.0.1.msi.
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:52]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4EF7CA29-A8E3-4755-9009-C6CF8EE3325B}v4.0.21147\dotnet-host-win-x64.1.0.1.msi.
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:53]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5C55840C-94E5-40CB-B709-15A0F57D7637}v1.1.1\dotnet-sharedframework-win-x64.1.1.1.msi.
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:53]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{F70725AC-A5A7-418B-BB66-70005DC505C2}v4.16.1374\dotnet-hostfxr-win-x64.1.1.0.msi.
[2864:130C][2017-03-08T15:02:53]i305: Verified acquired payload: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{CA2A9E77-78D9-4BCC-BA1F-1F9E3E795329}v4.16.1374\dotnet-host-win-x64.1.1.0.msi.
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:02:53]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3A36F010-62C4-4173-9F25-257F1B0899DD}v4.0.4911\dotnet-sdk-win-x64.1.0.0.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" DOTNETHOME="C:\Program Files\dotnet"'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:03]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:03]i325: Registering dependency: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322} on package provider: Dotnet_CLI_1.0.0_x64, package: dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:03]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3C83FDBB-34EF-401F-AC13-F234BD57FA1A}v1.0.4\dotnet-sharedframework-win-x64.1.0.4.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" DOTNETHOME="C:\Program Files\dotnet"'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:13]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:13]i325: Registering dependency: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322} on package provider: DotNet.CLI.SharedFramework.Microsoft.NETCore.App_1.0.4_x64, package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:13]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E1197A14-9403-4F4C-8272-38FB20DF8CF5}v4.0.21147\dotnet-hostfxr-win-x64.1.0.1.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" DOTNETHOME="C:\Program Files\dotnet"'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:15]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:15]i325: Registering dependency: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322} on package provider: Dotnet_CLI_HostFxr_1.0.1_x64, package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:15]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4EF7CA29-A8E3-4755-9009-C6CF8EE3325B}v4.0.21147\dotnet-host-win-x64.1.0.1.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" DOTNETHOME="C:\Program Files\dotnet"'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:17]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:17]i325: Registering dependency: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322} on package provider: Dotnet_CLI_SharedHost_x64, package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:17]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5C55840C-94E5-40CB-B709-15A0F57D7637}v1.1.1\dotnet-sharedframework-win-x64.1.1.1.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" DOTNETHOME="C:\Program Files\dotnet"'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:21]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:21]i325: Registering dependency: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322} on package provider: DotNet.CLI.SharedFramework.Microsoft.NETCore.App_1.1.1_x64, package: dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:21]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{F70725AC-A5A7-418B-BB66-70005DC505C2}v4.16.1374\dotnet-hostfxr-win-x64.1.1.0.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" DOTNETHOME="C:\Program Files\dotnet"'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:22]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:22]i325: Registering dependency: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322} on package provider: Dotnet_CLI_HostFxr_1.1.0_x64, package: dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:22]i301: Applying execute package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{CA2A9E77-78D9-4BCC-BA1F-1F9E3E795329}v4.16.1374\dotnet-host-win-x64.1.1.0.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" DOTNETHOME="C:\Program Files\dotnet"'
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i319: Applied execute package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i325: Registering dependency: {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322} on package provider: Dotnet_CLI_SharedHost_x64, package: dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[2864:0DF4][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: BUNDLEMONIKER = .NET Core SDK 1.0.0 (x64) Installer
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: DOTNETHOME = C:\Program Files\dotnet
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: ProgramFiles6432Folder = C:\Program Files\
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: VCRedist_KeyExists = 1
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: VCRedist_KeyValue = v14.10.25008.00
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 1.0.0.0
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLastUsedSource = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\Waqas
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_003_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_006_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_002_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_005_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_000_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_001_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_004_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = .NET Core SDK 1.0.0 (x64) Installer (x64)
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {c7c7d963-f622-455d-879a-7ffa111d1322}
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_003_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.0.1.msi_rollback.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_006_dotnet_host_win_x64.1.1.0.msi_rollback.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_002_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.0.1.msi_rollback.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_005_dotnet_hostfxr_win_x64.1.1.0.msi_rollback.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_000_dotnet_sdk_win_x64.1.0.0.msi_rollback.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_001_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.0.4.msi_rollback.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi = C:\Users\Waqas_004_dotnet_sharedframework_win_x64.1.1.1.msi_rollback.log
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK,version=15.0.26228.0,chip=x64\dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0.exe
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.0.0.0
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i410: Variable: WixStdBALanguageId = 1033
[2130:3048][2017-03-08T15:03:24]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

I installed following components
- Xamarin
- Asp.Net
- Universal App Development
- .Net Core 
- Desktop Development

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @MuazzamAli for finding the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43049052/3180309

The problem might be that VS 2017 will create a folder called "1.0.0" in "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk"

[image: After Visual Studio 2017]

Then when you open VS 2015, it will look at that folder instead of the correct one.  Before you open VS 2015 to rename that folder to something like "x.x.x"

[image: rename]

Then open VS 2015 and it will find the correct version of dotnet core sdk.

When you go back to VS 2017, remember to rename "x.x.x" back to "1.0.0"