# ASP.NET MVC 5 errors while loading the project to Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I had Install Visual Studio 2015 and Created  web app project from ASP.NET 5 Templates then i Installed the Visual Studio code open my project with it it gives me some recommends to install some extensions like C# .. etc after installing the extensions the project give me these error i searched for some solution like install .NET Core SDK but it didn't solve my problem another I tried to open the terminal and write dotnet restore command it gives me an error that error MSB4019:

> The imported project "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

then i check the `DemoCore.xproj` file and i found an wrong path in it    but i don't know what to do 
these errors in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdeRE.png)shows the problem in the visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed .NET Core 1.0.4? See the stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020289/microsoft-dotnet-props-was-not-found). Note that the selected answer in that linked question recommends installing Visual Studio 2015 Tools, which comes with .NET Core 1.0.1.. You'll want 1.0.4 or higher from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core), and may need to upgrade the target .NET Core framework version of your project in order to get it to build if you end up installing .NET Core 1.1 or 2.0.