# I am trying to create an AWS Lambda Project (.Net Core). But its giving me the following error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, aws-lambda

I am trying to create an AWS Lambda Project (.Net Core) in Visual Studio 2015. But its giving me the following error.

> The imported project "C:\Program
>   Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\v14.0\Dotnet\Microsoft.Dotnet.Props" was
>   not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>
> C:\Users....\AWSLabmda1\AWSLambda1.xproj

I want to create and publish the project. My Machine is Windows 10 64 bit.

I tried this link ([Microsoft.DotNet.Props was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020289/microsoft-dotnet-props-was-not-found)). But the Visual Studio 2015 Tools (Preview 2) is not getting installed in my machine. I have Windows 10 64 bit machine and I am running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.DotNet.Props was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020289/microsoft-dotnet-props-was-not-found)

Comment: I tried this link (Microsoft.DotNet.Props was not found). But the Visual Studio 2015 Tools (Preview 2) is not getting installed in my machine. I have Windows 10 64 bit machine and I am running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.